# set id on select option to disabled javascript

Tags: javascript, html, disabled-control

I want to disabled option on select without click any button. How can I do that?
I tried this. use id on option in JS

html code:

```
<select name="select01" id="select01" onchange="handleSelect()">
 <option value="01" id="01">01</option>
 <option value="02" id="02">02</option>
 <option value="03" id="03">03</option>
</select>
```

JS code:

```
<script>
function handleSelect() {
if (this.value == '02') {
    document.getElementById('02').disabled=true;
  }
}
</script>
```

From what I know from the code JS, option with id 02 will be disabled but it it does not work. I have tried search inside stack over flow but do not find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your eventhandler you need to pass in the element `onchange="handleSelect(this)"`. Then use it:

```
function handleSelect(ele) {
    if (ele.value == '02') {
        document.getElementById('02').disabled=true;
    }
}
```

Also note that `id` isn't supposed to be strictly numerical, while it's supported in HTML 5 it isn't below HTML 4.01 where it needs to start with a letter.

Also if you attach the event handler purely in JavaScript you can just do:

```
document.getElementById("select01").onchange = function() {
    if (this.value == '02') {
        document.getElementById('02').disabled=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MaxMastalerz Why would it not be, `this` would refer to the element that the event is being attached to?

Comment: @MaxMastalerz `this` is a keyword, you can't use it as a variable name in your parameter. [Here is how it would be in an example](http://jsfiddle.net/0omwhn15/).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek the code does not work. You give the example in http://jsfiddle.net/0omwhn15/ here, you can see option 02 not disabled.

Comment: @FaiZalDong It does work. It only happens when the `02` item is selected, as given in your provided code. Select that item and then when you click on the selection again it will be disabled. Although if you want it disabled from the start all you need is the [`document.getElementById('02').disabled=true` part](http://jsfiddle.net/0omwhn15/1/)

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I just copy and paste ur code. but still not work. why?
for javascript, I already open the JS tag inside my php file

Comment: @FaiZalDong Make sure that code is executed after the element with the `id` of `02` is created in the DOM. Also make sure that you are using HTML5 (having `<!DOCTYPE html> ` at the top of the HTML file).